# Find columns with NULL values in Teradata

Tags: sql, null, teradata

I would like to find the columns in a table that has a null value in it.
Is there a system table that have that information?

Answer (score 4):

To find columns where "null" values are allowed try...

```
select *
from dbc.columns 
where databasename = 'your_db_name'
and tablename = 'your_table_name'
and Nullable = 'Y'
```

then to identify the specific rows w/ null values, take the "ColumnName" from the previous result set and run queries to identify results... perhaps throw them in a volatile table if you want to take further action on them (update,delete).

```
-- for example you found out that column "foo" is nullable... 
create volatile table isnull_foo_col
as
(
  sel * 
  from your_table_name 
  where foo is null
) with data 
on commit preserve rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have statistics collected on the column you can use the views found **[here](http://www.teradataforum.com/teradata/20100531_172525.htm)** for Teradata 12.0.03+ and Teradata 13.0.02+ to determine the number of records in the table that have NULL values.

In Teradata 14, if you use the `SHOW STATISTICS` with the `VALUES` clause you will get similar information generated by the views listed at the link above.

You can use the DBC.Columns data dictionary view to determine what columns in a particular table are nullable.