# How to select all non-null columns?

Tags: sql, r, vertica

I am sending the query to `VERTICA(SQL)` using `R ODBC` package. I am looking for a fast solution which will select all non-null columns from Table A and put them to new table B.

I have created and function which is in my opinion highly inefficient, but I don't know how to make it faster. The function takes max for every single column in a table and selects it if the `MAX` is not null. Putting everything into one query wouldn't change much because `Vertica` is a column database.

```
  reduce_width <- function(in_name, out_name) {
  query_in <- paste('SELECT * FROM', in_name, 'LIMIT 1;', sep = ' ')

vertica_answer <- dbGetQuery(conn, query_in)

var_names <- colnames(vertica_answer)

lenght <- length(var_names)

var_names <- as.data.frame(var_names, stringsAsFactors = F)

var_names$is_null <- 0

for(i in 1:lenght){
    name <- as.character(var_names[i,1])
    query_max <- paste('SELECT MAX(',name,') from', in_name,';', sep = ' ')
    max_value <- dbGetQuery(conn, query_max)
    if(is.na(max_value[1,1])){ 
      var_names$is_null[i]<-0
    } else {
      var_names $is_null[i]<-1
    }
  }

not_null_collumns <-var_names %>% filter(is_null==1) %>% select(var_names)

not_null_collumns <- (as.character(t(not_null_collumns$var_names)))

query_front <- 'SELECT'
  for(i in 1:(length(not_null_collumns)-1))  {
    query_front <- paste(query_front, not_null_collumns[i],',', sep = ' ')
  }

query_front <- paste(query_front, 
  not_null_collumns[length(not_null_collumns)], sep = ' ')

query_back <- paste('into', out_name, 'from', in_name , sep = ' ')

query_create <- paste(query_front, query_back, sep = ' ')

dbSendQuery(conn, query_create)
}
```

How can I make my solution faster?

Comment: Ciao Ravioli - do I understand that right - you are looking for all columns in a source table of which at least one occurrence is not NULL - in other words - all columns of a table except those that are always NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should query all at once:

```
query_all <- paste('SELECT * FROM', in_name, ';', sep = ' ')

vertica_answer <- dbGetQuery(conn, query_all)

Vertica_sub <- vertica_answer[ , colSums(is.na(vertica_answer)) == 0]

#or just non null columns

non_null_cols <- names(verica_answer)[colSums(is.na(vertica_answer)) == 0]
```

You are already querying the data in your loop. This is more efficient because there is overhead for each query that is run.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two separate parts here:

**1) Build the SELECT list**
You can do this in your script or a stored procedure / function, but I don't think it will have much impact on performance.

**2) Check if a column has a NULL value**
This is where you'll have the biggest performance hit.  A couple ideas to try:

- Some databases store whether a column is `NULLable` in their data dictionary.  You may be able to use this to filter out the NULLable columns.  Links: [Oracle](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/oracle/check-column-nullable), [Teradata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533202/find-columns-with-null-values-in-teradata)
- Try another calculation instead of `MAX`.  Maybe `COUNT` will be faster since it won't have to sort / compare values.  The logic would be something like this:

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN (
    COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) - -- Get total row count
    COALESCE(COUNT(col1), 0) -- Get # non-NULL values in col1
  ) = 0 THEN 'No Nulls' 
  ELSE 'Has Nulls' 
END AS col1_NullValuesCheck
```

You could do the `COUNT(*)` calculation once, store it and compare it to the `COUNT(colX)` values.

- Use the `EXISTS` operator:
  `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE col1 IS NULL)`

I agree with the previous poster, it'd probably be better to combine this into a single query.